# Get selected li

Tags: asp.net, css, html-lists

hi i have master page and menu like this

```
<ul id="ulhotel" runat="server">
            <li class="userprof active"><a href="AddAdminDetail.aspx">
                <p class="activenav">
                    <span class="entypo activenav">+</span>User Profile</p>
            </a></li>
            <li class="hoteldetails"><a href="AddHotelDetails.aspx">
                <p>
                    <span class="entypo">j</span>Hotel Details</p>
            </a></li>
            <li class="hoteldirectory"><a href="AddHotelDirectory.aspx">
                <p>
                    <span class="entypo">l</span>Hotel Directory</p>
            </a></li>
            <li class="appconfig"><a href="Appconfiguration.aspx">
                <p>
                    <span class="entypo">@</span>App Configurate</p>
            </a></li>
            <li class="featoffers"><a href="OfferDashboard.aspx">
                <p>
                    <span class="entypo">C</span>Offer Dashboard</p>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
```

now right now User Profile Is seleted now when i Click HotelDetail  link I want to change it same as User Profile

i am trying this but its not working

```
 $('#ulhotel li').click(function()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `activenav` to the class string for Hotel Details

Comment: @ Explosion Pills I m Using Masterpage

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
AddAdminDetail.aspx
AddHotelDetails.aspx
AddHotelDirectory.aspx
Appconfiguration.aspx
OfferDashboard.aspx
```

five different pages so you can also add `active` class to appropriate `li` tag on related page.

**Comment Response**

```
$('#ulhotel li').on('click',function(e)
```

and then set cookies for clicked `li`  now when page redirected use that previously set cookies and add active class to appropriate `li`.

Comment: Thanks  for Reply but i m using master page .

Comment: @ Dipesh i m getting Error like Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Comment: @Khushbu oh no...are you using jQuery..?? if yes then please update jQuery version...

Comment: yes i'm using   ** <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>**

Comment: can u tell me Which version ?

Comment: @Khushbu so please update it to newer version and then try...i am sure it will work.. version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

It is due to when you click link each time master page is loading.

you have to use script to change class in AddHotelDetails.aspx page to active related li.

In AddHotelDetails.aspx page you can use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ulhotel li').removeClass("active");

  $('#ulhotel li.hoteldetails').addClass("active");
  });
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: hii but i want to apply active class to <p> tag  in <li> can u help me ?